# Why I am getting blank response from the AWS lambda function even though AWS lambda test works properly?

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

##### Description

---

> I am creating an intermediary service between my frontend and my backend using AWS lambda function.
> The job of the function is to take the payload from the UI and send to the backend, if Backend is live then send the `200` status (progress of ML model, short pooling). Suppose the backend is not live and the backend pod is restarting use the previous JSON saved inside a `response.json` file and return that back to the frontend until the pod is restarted and live to serve.
> Here is my lambda function.

---

My AWS Lambda code

```py
import json
import os
import requests
import boto3

# Initialize the S3 client
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def save_json_file_to_s3(response_payload, filename="response.json"):
    
    # Name of your S3 bucket
    bucket_name = 'mys3store'
    s3.put_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=filename, Body=json.dumps(response_payload))


def read_json_file_from_s3(filename="response.json"):
    bucket_name = 'mys3store'
    response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=filename)
    content = response['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
    response_payload= json.loads(content)


    return response_payload

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    """Forwards a POST request to another service and redirects back to the first microservice.

    Args:
        event: The Lambda event.
        context: The Lambda context.

    Returns:
        A JSON response object.
    """
    
    print(event)
    print(type(event))
    print("=========================================================")

    # Get the request data from the event.
    
    try:
        request_data = json.loads(event["body"])
    except KeyError as e:
        request_data = event

    # Get the destination URL from the request data.
    dest_url = request_data["dest_url"]

    # Forward the POST request to the destination service.
    response = requests.post(dest_url, json=request_data)

    # Check the response status code.
    if response.status_code == 200:
        # Get the response payload.
        response_payload = json.loads(response.content)
        print("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
        print(response_payload)
        print("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
        # Save the response payload to a temporary file.
        save_json_file_to_s3(response_payload)

        # Redirect back to the first microservice with the response payload.
        return {
            "statusCode": 200,
            "body": json.dumps(response_payload),
            "headers": {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        }
    elif response.status_code == 502:
        # Read the response payload from the temporary file.
        response_payload = read_json_file_from_s3()

        # Redirect back to the first microservice with the response payload.
        return {
            "statusCode": 200,
            "body": json.dumps(response_payload),
            "headers": {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        }
    else:
        # Return an error response.
        return {
            "statusCode": 500,
            "body": json.dumps({
                "error": "Unexpected response from destination service."
            }),
            "headers": {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        }
```

---

Now to test the lambda I created a test event `checkLiveOrNot`

```
{
  "app": "my_app",
  "session_id": "3432428374827347234",
  "table": "progress",
  "user_id": "myaccount@gmail.cm",
  "flag": false,
  "project_name": "mybig1gbproject",
  "user_name": "john doe",
  "file_name": "",
  "fit_progress": 0,
  "model_fit": 0,
  "total_fit": 0,
  "model_calc": 0,
  "total_calc": 0,
  "calc_progress": 0,
  "model_arch": "lambda",
  "dest_url": "https://mybackendservice/api/maincore/progress"
}
```

and invoked and it returned me the proper output in the lambda test console.

```
Test Event Name
checkLiveOrNot

Response
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "{\"_id\": \"34347tyi738483h8d73h\", \"session_id\": \"3432428374827347234\", \"data\": 0, \"model_no\": 0, \"table\": \"progress\", \"total_fit\": 1, \"total_calc\": 1, \"orc_fail\": 0, \"model_progress\": 0.0, \"current_model\": 0, \"model_progress\": 100.0, \"current_calc\": 1}",
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }
}

Function Logs
START RequestId: 0d820ce34rtry9-2e11-420dsdfa-961e-c4434515b18f Version: $LATEST
{'app': 'my-app', 'session_id': '34347tyi738483h8d73h', 'table': 'progress', 'user_id': 'danish.xavier@iqvia.com', 's3_flag': False, 'project_name': 'checksampleforapitesting', 'user_name': 'danish.xavier', 'file_name': '', 'model_fit_progress': 0, 'current_model_fit': 0, 'total_model_fit': 0, 'current_model_calc': 0, 'total_model_calc': 0, 'model_calc_progress': 0, 'model_arch': 'eks', 'dest_url': 'https://promo-internal-promo-usv-demotemp-env.mmx.mco.solutions.iqvia.com/api/core/progress_lambda'}
<class 'dict'>
=========================================================
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
{'_id': '34347tyi738483h8d73h', 'session_id': '34347tyi738483h8d73h', 'data': 0, 'model_no': 0, 'table': 'progress', 'total_fit': 1, 'total_calc': 1, 'orc_fail': 0, 'model_progress': 0.0, 'current_model': 0, 'model_progress': 100.0, 'current_calc': 1}
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
END RequestId: 0d820ce9-2e11-420a-961e-c4434515b18f
REPORT RequestId: 0d82dfdf0ce9-2dfdfe11-42dfdf0a-961e-c44345dfdf15b18f  Duration: 281.79 ms Billed Duration: 282 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 54 MB  Init Duration: 324.60 ms

Request ID
0d820ce9-2e11-420a-961e-c4434515b18f
```

> Now when I sent a POST request to this lambda  via postman with the same payload I am getting 200 Response but showing nothing on the Postman screen. I tried using python and sent request.
> here is the code.

---

```py
import json
import requests

# Create the request headers
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

# Create the request body
payload = {
  "app": "my_app",
  "session_id": "3432428374827347234",
  "table": "progress",
  "user_id": "myaccount@gmail.cm",
  "flag": false,
  "project_name": "mybig1gbproject",
  "user_name": "john doe",
  "file_name": "",
  "fit_progress": 0,
  "model_fit": 0,
  "total_fit": 0,
  "model_calc": 0,
  "total_calc": 0,
  "calc_progress": 0,
  "model_arch": "lambda",
  "dest_url": "https://mybackendservice/api/maincore/progress"
}

# Send the POST request
response = requests.post(
    'https://8973043wa7lrta.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/progress_lambda',
    headers=headers,
    json=payload
)

# Check the response status code
if response.status_code == 200:
    # The request was successful
    print('Request successful')

    # Get the response payload
    response_payload = response.content

    print(response_payload)
```

The Output from the program:

```
Request successful
b''
```

Comment: What exactly is the value of `event["body"]` or the full `event`?

Comment: Not a (complete) answer, but remember that lambdas are transient. The json file written during one call will be lost at the end of the call, and won't exist for the next lambda call.  You would need to use eg. S3 for permanent storage.

Comment: @Marcin The event is `checkLiveOrNot` Given in the question

Comment: @Guillaume I understand that for storing the states in stead of storing in the Ephemeral storage I can store that in the s3 bucket. In my code `if response.status==200` I am sending the response_payload back I understand the `save_json_file_to_tmp` wont work or nothing will be there, but the response_apyload should have been returned right ?

Comment: @Guillaume to clarify: the json file written to `/tmp` during one invocation *may* still exist for the next invocation, but is not guaranteed to exist. See [runtime lifecycle](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtime-environment.html#runtimes-lifecycle).

Comment: If you want to cache responses to smooth out backend failures, then use a cache e.g. Redis.

Comment: How events are presented to your Lambda function depends on your API Gateway integration. Typically, the `event` parameter is more complex than your test event `checkLiveOrNot` (i.e. your test event, while working, may actually be incorrect). Print the `event` parameter in the Lambda function when invoked via API Gateway.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your function correctly : you use the directory */tmp* to save the result of a call to an external service (API or something else). Later, when the Lambda function is called again, and in the same time the external service returns 502 instead of 200, you want the Lambda function re-use the response previously saved.

But this is not possible to do that using the temporary directory */tmp*.
This directory can be used in a Lambda function, but only for saving something which is re-used in the same execution of the Lambda function. */tmp* is not shared between multiple instances of the same Lambda Function.

The solution could be to not write/read using */tmp*, but instead to use an external service to write/read the response, like S3, or any other database or caching system.

Check-out the [AWS Lambda FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/?nc1=h_ls) :

> If your application needs durable, persistent storage, consider using Amazon S3 or Amazon EFS. If your application requires storing data needed by code in a single function invocation, consider using AWS Lambda ephemeral storage as a transient cache.

An also :

> Keeping functions stateless enables AWS Lambda to rapidly launch as many copies of the function as needed to scale to the rate of incoming events. While AWS Lambda’s programming model is stateless, your code can access stateful data by calling other web services, such as Amazon S3 or Amazon DynamoDB.

Comment: Not quite. The `/tmp` contents persist as long as that Lambda execution environment lives. It can and will be used for subsequent warm starts that reuse the same execution environment. That said, while Lambda functions can take advantage of this, they should be written to handle both the cold start scenario where `/tmp` is empty and the warm start scenario, where the current function invocation's `/tmp` contains whatever the prior invocation left there.

Comment: @jarmod @0urz4g . Thank you for explaining me. I have added an S3 store to store my JSON output. It still does not retrieve me the messages. I am thinking the error lies in the flow my frontend give HTTP POST request hits the AWS API gateway which triggers this AWS lambda function and this lambda function triggers my FLASK server running in a POD in a k8 cluster, this lambda gets it 200 response from the POD, but I think it does not forward the request again, so the API gateway is giving `b''` response. What do you think ?

Comment: Indeed it is a potential issue to your problem. So to be sure about the Lambda response : firstly, when you run the test mode, does the file in S3 is correctly saved ? Secondly, just change the code to force to respond with the file on S3. Redo a test. Is the response is well returned in the execution result ? If yes, you should consider solving this question, and opening a new question for problems on API gateway if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

From your explanations it sounds as if the invocationType might be asynchronous for your python or postman requests.

Perhaps adding the header:

```
'InvocationType': 'RequestResponse'
```

is solving your issue